# Generic parameter base type: "There is no implicit reference conversion from B to A"

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class A
{
    public A()
    {

    }
}

[Serializable]
public class B : A
{
    public B() : base()
    {

    }
}
```

In an extension:

```
public static T NextRecord<T>(this SqlDataReader reader) where T : A, new()
{
    // Do work
}
```

I call this extension like so:

```
B b = reader.NextRecord<B>();
```

Yet, I get this exception: "There is no implicit reference conversion from 'B' to 'A'."

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

**Edit**

```
public static T NextRecord<T>(this SqlDataReader reader) where T : A, new()
{
    // Make sure we have been given a correct Type
    if (!typeof(T).BaseType.Equals(typeof(A)))
    {
        throw new Exception("Supplied Type is not derived from Type A");
    }

    if (reader.IsNull())
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("reader is null");
    }

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            // Instance a object of the type, passing it the SqlDataReader so that it can populate itself   
            return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { reader }) as T;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Here's the code for the extension

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you sure you're not confusing different types with the same name or something like that? Could you post a short but complete example program that exhibits this error?

Comment: This mean there is a problem in implementation of the extension method. Show extension method.

Comment: Added the extension code

Comment: I know this isn't a part of your question, but you don't need to check if T is of type A. Your constraint for the generic will take care of that at compile time.

Comment: Your `typeof` check at the beginning is redundant due to the generic constraint, but will also fail if `T` is not directly derived from `A` which is probably not what you want. The `new()` constraint is also odd if you're going to look for a non-default constructor in the method.

Comment: IT compiles/ works here as well. Probably theres something else in your code that causes the error and you didnt post here/ are missing

Comment: I know the typeof is not needed, that code is old, from when i wasnt using generics. That, and the new() from what I can see has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I should say it works if I replace "where T : A" with "where T : class" What else could it be...?

Comment: Hovering over the types in VS all show the right ones (namespace, clicking 'Go to Def')

Comment: Given that it works when you remove the constraint, it sounds like the "A" that is being used for the constraint isn't the same "A" that "B" derives from. Have you tried replacing "A" in the generic constraint with the fully qualified type name (i.e. SomeNamespace.OtherNamespace.A)?

Answer (score 0):

Still having problems with this, although i sort of fixed the problem by changing where T : A to where T : class.

I have a 2nd problem:

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public static void Test(SomeClassBase obj)
    {

    }
}

public abstract class SomeClassBase
{
    public SomeClassBase()
    {
        SomeOtherClass.Test(this);
    }
}

public class SomeClass : SomeClassBase
{
    public SomeClass() : base()
    {

    }
}
```

I Get this exception:

"The best overloaded method match for 'Namespace.SomeOtherClass.Test(Namespace.SomeClass)' has some invalid arguments"

However, removing the mothod call from the ctor and calling it outside will work, like so:

SomeClass s = new SomeClass();
SomeOtherClass.Test(s);

Even changing the method to:

```
public static void Test(SomeClass obj)
{

}
```

will fail :(

and if i move the method call to the derived class ctor...

Comment: I ran the above code in a separate solution and it worked... but it's basically exactly the same (method/class signatures, etc) as the real code.. just all the logic stripped out

Comment: Fixed my second problem! :) .. I moved the classes out of a file that had its build action set to 'Content' (as it was a page) into a normal .cs file with  the build action set to 'Compile'..It broke one of my extensions oddly so i'm having to fix that now :/